# How to prove that $\mathbb Z_p$ over $\mathbb Z$ is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I tried to prove it using all the properties of vector space by selecting a particular value of p. But how to solve it in generalize form?

Comment: First, $\mathbb Z$ is not a field so you can't talk about "$ \mathbb Z_p$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Z$ ". You might be trying to show that $ \mathbb Z_p$ is a $ \mathbb Z$-module. Also, why are you choosing a particular value of $p$? It is quite easy to show it for any prime $p$.

Comment: Do you believe that you will get more answers because you created a profile with a picture of Mehwish Hayat instead of your real picture?

Comment: Oh my God.. i want a maths answer. M nt flirting with any one dat u r concerned about my profile pic

Comment: @EternalBlood thanx